# Not able to type any character into any input fields on Salesforce community pages

Tags: community

Recently I faced an issue the community cloud pages,
whatever the input fields were there on the page I was not able to type any character into it.
For any input fields like lightning : text input or lightning : text area when I clicked on the input
field to type into it the cursor used to come and immediately used to go away, and cursor was not
longer available to type. Again if I click on the input field, cursor used to come and go again immediately.

Only if I kept the mouse left click pressed and held it only then the cursor used to stay and I was able to
input character into that input field.

In JavaScript terms, the input field use to loose focus immediately, this was a strange behavior as earlier it
worked as expected then this issue came all of the sudden and went away on its own.

Can anyone suggest what could have been the cause and how it went away on its own, does it have to do something with salesforce releases?

Answer (score 0):

This was because of performance degradation issue which happened on salesforce side as confirmed by salesforce itself. However it got resolved on its own after few days.